# Regex match all spaces in sentences containing certain character

Tags: regex, arguments

i'm looking for the correct regex to match all spaces in sentences containing "->".

```
.*->.*\r?
```

works to select all the correct sentences, but i have difficulties connecting it with /s

Sample Text: I try to reformat subtitle text. I need to take all the spaces out of the timecode:

```
7
00: 00: 20,509 -> 00: 00: 25,059
on the data before and does not shy in front of radical solutions such as post privacy back.

8
00: 00: 25,159 -> 00: 00: 27,896
On his blog writes sower already since 2011

9
00: 00: 27,996 -> 00: 00: 31,784
on the impact of technology on society, politics and economy.
```

And the expected Result would be:

```
7
00:00:20,509->00:00:25,059
on the data before and does not shy in front of radical solutions such as post privacy back.
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: think you mean this `\s*->\s*`

Comment: Can you add examples of what would be the sentences you are trying to match ?

Comment: Can you put here an expected result?

Comment: @JorgeCampos sorry, added some sample text :)

Comment: Can you do this with two steps? The first step spots the lines with `->`, the second steps replaces the whitespace

Comment: What is the language (programming) you are using?

Comment: @JorgeCampos actually I need it to run trough a Batch. I got over 100 files that need the timecode to be corrected. I'm using Text Crawler 3

Comment: Do you really need to suppress the spaces around `->` ?  If not something along `sed 's/: /:/g' file` should do

Comment: @Tensibai well actually I need the result to be: `00:00:20,509 --> 00:00:25,059`

Comment: @Tensibai awesome that worked. Thanks a lot! Still I'd be interested in the correct regex expression :)

Comment: @vinni made an answer with other options more than the simple `: `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few solution more complex than just `:` (colon and space) in regex according to your sample:

[first one](https://regex101.com/r/jD2hY9/1)

`((?:(?<\d:)|(?<=->)) | (?=->))` Will select space only if preceded by `[0-9]:` or by `->` or a space immediately followed by `->`

[A shorter one](https://regex101.com/r/jD2hY9/2) (but more error proof):

`((?:(?<=:|>)) | (?=->))` Same idea as above with alternation in the look ahead.

[The most exact one](https://regex101.com/r/jD2hY9/3) which match exactly your format but need a replacement by `\1\2\3-->\4\5\6` instead of by nothing

`(\d{2}:) (\d{2}:) ([0-9,]+) -> (\d{2}:) (\d{2}:) ([0-9,]+)`